# Working with Bugs in TFS2010 (Agile Template)

Tags: agile

My current work involves working on a large number of bugs.
We normally (non TFS) would add these to an iteration backlog (grouped into Stories) after estimating and prioritising; then work through, mark actual effort.

I want to try and understand how I would work on these bugs using the TFS Agile template as intended. But am really struggling to find best practices and examples specifically for bugs for the TFS Agile template in TFS2010.

Cheers, Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we have been doing is:

1. Raising bug during testing by a tester.
2. During iteration planning we may decide to allocate X amount of time to fix outstanding bugs, so we creat a bug fixing story for that iteration of X story points.
3. Bugs are chosen that we think should be fixed within the iteration, a task is created for each bug along with a time estimate and any high level technical details. Note the task is created as a child of the story and also related to the bug.

The key is that bug work items are not developed against directly, a related task is.

Answer (score 1):

I hear some parts in your question:

"Add these to an iteration backlog": you can use the iteration path of the work items. Best practice is to create an iteration called backlog.

"Grouped into Stories": In TFS 2010, the default traceablity is that on a User Story you define the Test Cases which validate the User Story. The Bugs are reported against the Test Cases.

"Estimating": You can use the Remaining work field for that

"Prioritsing": You can use the Stack Rank field

"Mark actual effort": Use the Completed work field